# Firebase error reading fsCachedData

Tags: ios, firebase

I have two apps with different bundle IDs (com.myapp.debug and com.myapp.release) installed on my phone. And I got the following error sometimes. I don't know exact steps to reproduce it. But it doesn't happen if I only have one flavor of the app installed. And it seems to happen when in have both flavors and I do install/uninstall of my apps frequently. And the error happens when I'm running the debug version of the app and somehow it tries to read the fsCachedData in the wrong app (release version instead of debug version) as the error message indicates.

```
*** INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D8041C7A-FE4A-49D1-A3BA-9E3A51F8ECD5/Library/Caches/com.myapp.release/fsCachedData/49409173-05E8-4291-B22E-6859D4026657. Errno: 1
```

Any idea why this is happening and how do I get rid of it?